# How to change cell colour in Excel 2010 based on certain criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like a cell's colour to change when its value is less than that of another cell. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific, maybe provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/849-excel-change-background-color-based-on-cell-value.html) site contains instructions for setting up rules to change cell colors based on values.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I was waiting for a little more information from user199866, before I invested the time.

Comment: @wizlog: Answers you post on [su] should help *future* visitors just as they should help the OP. So your investment may be worthy either way :)